# Remove non-ascii characters from a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, non-ascii-characters

I am grep'ing the output of a command inside shell script and store the result in a variable.

There is a very corner case where this variable might have non-ascii characters because of parse logic used by grep.

Question: How do I remove these non-ascii characters from this variable inside the shell script, so that I can use the variable in the subsequent commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using bash, and if your variable is called `var`, then

```
"${var//[^[:ascii:]]/}"
```

will expand to `var` with all non-ascii characters removed. So:

```
var_non_ascii=${var//[^[:ascii:]]/}
```

should do. (This is definitely the best method: no sub-shells and no forks to external processes to bash).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your variable is var, try this:

```
var=$(echo $var | sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g')
```

This should remove the non-ascii characters

Comment: I am selecting the other answer since that doesn't involve an external process. Upvoted though :)